# What physical effects cause materialization of a system of particles for a short time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, string-theory, mathematical-physics

It is well-known from physics that a photon with enough energy creates a pair of particles: one electron and one positron. This pair of particles can only exist for a short time. This process is governed by the term $e \psi^\dagger \gamma^\mu A_\mu \psi$ in the Lagrangian density of the Feynman Propagator.

Now I am thinking about the creation of **multiple** particles that are annihilated after a short time. Can this be modeled also by a Lagrangian? Expressed in less technical words: Assuming that one particle system occurs in a certain Region of spacetime, in which cases it is possible that a copy of this particle System occurs at a later instant of time (similar to teleportation) for a short time? How a Lagrangian can be constructed for such interesting vacuum fluctuations?

Is such a phenomenon possible if spacetime has a very Special topology or geometry?

Are brane-world interactions proposed in String theory (what are These in less technical sense?) modelling such phenomena?